# Discord.py bot resending messages to another channel breaking when reaction added

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot to take all of the messages send in a channel and resending them in another channel.
Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    channel = message.channel
    content = message.content
    author = message.author.name
    if channel.id == channelid1
        channel.id = channelid2
        await channel.send(author + ": " + content)
        channel.id = channelid1
```

It works fine, however as soon as a reaction is added to any message the bot breaks giving this error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\nij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", 
line 407, in parse_message_reaction_add
    emoji = PartialEmoji.with_state(self, animated=emoji_data['animated'], id=emoji_id, 
name=emoji_data['name'])
KeyError: 'animated'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? And if not does anyone know a way of making the bot automatically reconnect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This was [an issue with discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2422) (caused by [a breaking change in Discord's API](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/812#issuecomment-554142833)) that should be [fixed](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/89bfd9cc2029d76e7580e14543ddc66ea182bf30) in [v1.2.5](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#v1-2-5).